# LINQ: Groupby and Last

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ.

I have the following table:

```
ID  Field1  Field2      Field3
1   aaaa    20/01/2014  10
2   aaaa    21/01/2014  3
3   aaaa    25/01/2014  10
4   bbbb    01/01/2014  90
5   bbbb    03/01/2014  1
6   bbbb    31/01/2014  5
```

I want to group by Field1 and grab the last line of each group.
The SQL Query equivalent to this is:

```
SELECT Field1, Last(Field2) AS LastOfField2, Last(Field3) AS LastOfField3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Field1
```

How this can be achieved on Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = from p in Table1
group p by p.Field1 into grp
select grp.OrderByDescending(g=>g.Field2).First();
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked! I have a new question: Given the resultset with 2 records (one for aaaa and another for bbbb). I want to take only the record that has the lowest Field3. (Do I have to post a new question in the StackOverflow?)