# LINQ: Group and include the LET in the final result

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am continuing the [LINQ: Groupby and Last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959849/linq-groupby-and-last).

Basically I had the following table:

```
ID  Field1  Field2      Field3
1   aaaa    20/01/2014  10
2   aaaa    21/01/2014  3
3   aaaa    25/01/2014  10
4   bbbb    01/01/2014  90
5   bbbb    03/01/2014  10
6   bbbb    31/01/2014  5
```

I wanted to group by Field1 and grab the oldest line of each group based on Field2.

I also need to build some complex calculations based on field3 (I use "let" for this).
Now I use the "let" inside the Where Clause. This is all fine.

I have:

```
var result = from p in Table1
let MyLet = p.Field3 - 1 //This is actually very complex in the real scenario.
Where MyLet > 5
group p by p.Field1 into grp
select grp.OrderByDescending(g=>g.Field2).First();
```

Now... How to include MyLet into the final result, so it looks like this

```
ID  Field1  Field2      Field3 MyLet
3   aaaa    25/01/2014  10     9
5   bbbb    03/01/2014  10     9
```

Comment: `MyLet` is a variable which you have used for filtering. Exactly how you want to fetch that? Can you show any sample output?

Comment: I edited the question to include what the should looks like. NOTE: The row ID=6 is the oldest for Field1=bbbb, BUT, since MyLet in the WHERE clause filter "MyLet > 5" this row (ID=6) does not make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
  var result = from p in fields
                     let MyLet = p.Field3 - 1
                     where MyLet > 5
                     group new { p, MyLet } by p.Field1 into grp
                     let firstField = grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.p.Field2).First()
                     select new
                         {
                             ID = firstField.p.ID,
                             Field1 = firstField.p.Field1,
                             Field2 = firstField.p.Field2,
                             Field3 = firstField.p.Field3,
                             MyLet = firstField.MyLet
                         };
```

Please consider checking for Nulls before accessing the fields.

Comment: I think you nailed it. I am using a mix of current answer, and the previous one (before you edited it). BIG THANKS!

Comment: @danieljaguiar - Yup initially I got confused with your requirement but then got it correct. Happy to help :)